# Call an internal function in React component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

This component implements google recaptcha. This isn't the entire implementation, but this is similar.
I am trying to test if a onSuccess callback function has been called.

```
function ReCaptcha() {
  function onSuccess() {
    console.log("we are sucessful");
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    window.grecaptcha = {
      enterprise: {},
    };
    window.grecaptcha.enterprise = {
      execute: function (onSuccess) {
        //this part is done with google and it calls back onSuccess
      },
    };
    window.grecaptcha.enterprise.execute().then(() => {
      onSuccess();
    });
  }, []);
  return <h1>ReCaptcha</h1>;
}

export default ReCaptcha;
```

I have go through several attempts to call this function based on this article, but they haven't worked.

Ideally, I'd like to mock onSuccess and see if has been called.

```
onSuccess = jest.fn()
expect(onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock the `onSuccess` function. It's defined in functional scope, it's private. **You can't mock or spy it if you can't access it**.

You can spy on the `console.log` method. If it is called, it indirectly indicates that `onSuccess` was called. Just `console.log` doesn't make much sense, this is just a demo.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
//@ts-nocheck
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ReCaptcha() {
  function onSuccess() {
    console.log('we are sucessful');
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    window.grecaptcha = {
      enterprise: {},
    };
    window.grecaptcha.enterprise = {
      execute: function () {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          resolve();
        });
      },
    };
    window.grecaptcha.enterprise.execute().then(() => {
      onSuccess();
    });
  }, []);
  return <h1>ReCaptcha</h1>;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import ReCaptcha from './';

describe('ReCaptcha', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    render(<ReCaptcha />);
    await waitFor(() => expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('we are sucessful'));
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70457908/index.test.tsx (10.199 s)
  ReCaptcha
    ✓ should pass (75 ms)

  console.log
    we are sucessful

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:845:25)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.334 s
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have edited the question to make it clearer. Basically, the callback is out of my control. The Google recaptcha script calls it back when the user is successful, so in my test, onSuccess never is called.